# android - How do I get all the zip codes in a city with google places api?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

What I'm specifically looking for is a method from the Geocoder class or a method from the google places API where I can pass in either a lat/lon or a city and it returns me a list of zip codes from that region.

The closest I have is below:

```
 double lat = 100;
 double lon = 120;//random lat lon.
 int maxNumberOfResults = 100;
 Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity());
 List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, maxNumberOfResults);

 for (Address address : addresses) {
     Log.d("TAG", "zip code is " + address.getPostalCode());
 }
 //The Address class is from android.location package
```

However, the postal codes are either the same or null. Hoping someone has a solution here!